# Command sequence to reliably terminate LaTeX in batchmode

Tags: pdftex, automation

I'm looking for a command sequence that will terminate a running instance of

```
pdflatex --interaction batchmode
```

regardless of its state and prior input. I don't care about the output or error messages -- basically I want a "god version" of

```
\makeatletter\@@end
```

that terminates the `pdflatex` process even if the input just before that was

```
\newcommand{\iwannabeclever}{
```

or

```
\begin{verbatim}
```

. I was thinking about a long sequence of `}`, but then the catcode might have been changed (e.g., in verbatim mode).

### Application

I want to feed LaTeX through a fifo (created by `mkfifo`). This works, but closing the fifo doesn't seem to terminate the `pdflatex` process.

Comment: Maybe `nonstopmode`?

Comment: @Sigur: How does nonstopmode help here?

Comment: It will not stop with any error. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Sigur: No, I'm looking for quite the opposite: Always stop (when I say so), regardless of prior input.

Comment: From `man pdflatex`, maybe `-halt-on-error`.

Comment: I think `batchmode` implies `--halt-on-error`, but I might be wrong. This question is about *inducing* such an error that will effectively halt the process.

Comment: no, halt-on-error is needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use

```
 pdflatex --halt-on-error
```

then it will stop at the first error. One way of introducing an error is to use an illegal character. The only ones by default in LaTeX are 0 (ASCII NULL) and 127 (ASCII DEL). (In plain TeX just DEL is illegal, NULL is ignored.)

Normally you can enter that as `^^@` but if you want it to work even in verbatim you need an actual byte 0 in the input stream.

Comment: Thanks, works for me. Can the meaning of `ASCII NUL` be redefined?

Comment: @krlmlr yes it has no predefined meaning, it is just character 0 you could give it catcode 13 and then define it to say `hello world` but then it would not work for the above which relies on it being catcode 15 (invalid character)

Comment: Thanks again. A side note: [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Plain_TeX#Catcodes) claims that by default `ASCII NUL` is an "ignored character", and that `ASCII DEL` is invalid. According to our findings here this is wrong -- is it the other way round?

Comment: @krlmlr These are the default settings for Plain TeX. For LaTeX both are by default "invalid".